# I am having trouble pushing my rails app to Heroku/getting the 'pg' gem to install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, deployment

Originally I couldn't push my rails 4 app to heroku because my database was sqlite, and so now I have been trying to install the Postgresql gem ('pg') but I am not having any luck.  This is the error message I get in my terminal after running bundle install:

```
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

After running
    gem install pg -v '0.17.1' -–with-pg-config

I get this error in my terminal:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
 Illformed requirement ["0.17.1--with-pg_config"]
/project$ gem install pg -v '0.17.1'--with-pg-config
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pg' (= 0.17.1.pre..pre.with.pre.pg.pre.config) in   

any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: pg
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ubuntu, its a live USB if that makes a difference.

Comment: do you have postgress installed?

Comment: no I thought thats what I was trying to do. So i need something separate from the gem installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you don't have postgres installed**, you may want to go with:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

following by `gem install pg` and `bundle`.

**If you do have postgres installed** and running `gem install pg` doesn't work, you have to run `which pg_config` to get the path to your `pg_config`, and run `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= output_from_previous_command`.

Comment: This worked for deployment, but now my server isn't working but I guess that's a different problem